# count number of times key(name) was overridden

Tags: javascript

When we initialize an object with the same key(name) multiple times, the last assignment is kept. All previous iterations of the same key(name) are overridden. Is there a way to know the count of how many times JavaScript overrides a key(name)?

For e.g

```
var obj={a:1,b:2,a:3,b:4};
You end up with an object like this: {a:3,b:4}
```

Comment: no there is no way of doing that

Comment: Not at runtime. You might be able to do static code analysis and identify the number of occurrences of each key.

Comment: in "use strict" mode javascript don't allow Defining a property more than once in an object literal. use jshint validation

Comment: besides parsing a JSON string yourself, maybe if you do something like `{myFunc("a"):1,myFunc("b"):2,myFunc("a"):3,myFunc("b"):4}`

Comment: @ajax333221: You can't use arbitrary expressions as property names.

Answer (score 2):

Not natively: if you declare the object like that it's pretty much as if your first declarations of 'a' and 'b' never happened.  If you are creating the object via a JSON string, you'll likely have to write your own parser for that string to count the occurrences of the labels before creating the object.

Comment: +1 about passing it as a string (prefereably as JSON) and then parse it himself, that is like the only way possible